# Trouble trying to use CmdArgs in Haskell (Failed to load interface for ‘CmdArgs’)

Tags: haskell

I am currently trying to use CmdArgs and I am running into some trouble.

The code is [here on github](https://github.com/kuwze/gc2) and the error I am getting is this:

```
 $ stack build

 gc2-0.1.0.0: configure (lib + exe) Configuring
 gc2-0.1.0.0... gc2-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe) Preprocessing library
 gc2-0.1.0.0... Preprocessing executable 'gc2-exe' for gc2-0.1.0.0...
 [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs,
 .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/gc2-exe/gc2-exe-tmp/Main.o )

 /home/kuwze/src/haskell/gc2/app/Main.hs:6:1: error:
     Failed to load interface for ‘CmdArgs’
     Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

 --  While building package gc2-0.1.0.0 using:
       /home/kuwze/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build lib:gc2 exe:gc2-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
     Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the relevant source code and the Cabal file? Perhaps the error is in there.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out like usual I am an idiot.

The correct thing to do is to check the full path of a library; for my example the page for `CmdArgs` specifies that the library path for the module is `System.Console.CmdArgs`.

Comment: While I understand being self-deprecating, give yourself a bit of credit, too. No one remembers every module name. And you did figure it out yourself. Worst I can say is you're a bit trigger-happy on jumping to stack overflow. That's far from idiotic.